# Why should I insert blobs in database instead of filesystem?

Tags: database, blob, dao

I have to manage some files in a web application, let's say the avatar images of user profiles. 
I asked myself: should I use a blob field in user's database table or simply in a filesystem file like *avatars/{userid}.jpg*? What are advantages to store blob into database if I do not need search capabilities in this field?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is also the number of files. If you have to manage a large amount of files (>10.000 at least)  you have to think of organizing the files in a directory - structure, otherwise some filesystems may get slow. The DB usually takes care of that.

Also, if a user already has a connection to a database, you do not need to worry to setup a shared file to which all the users can connect. On the other hand, single file security management is a little harder in the database, sind you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are few advantages if you are not already running a database. If you are, you can take advantage of the caching features of that database, in some situations. For the most part, though, if you don't need to search, use the filesystem.